# Convert AJAX data into Excel using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, excel

Back-end is sending me data as Excel ByteArray format. I have to convert it into Excel and download the file in my local.

I am writing the following code, it converts the data into excel, but when I open the file I see only junk characters and no readable content is there.

```
       $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url: url
        })
        .done((data)=> {
            window.location.href = url;
            let bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
               bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            let blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

            let downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = "compare.xls";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        })
        .fail((err)=> {
        });
```

Please help !

Comment: What is "byteArray" ? Did you mean to use "bytes" which is the array defined earlier?

Comment: I mean the file is coming as binary from backend.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the file into an Excel? You could do an Ajax call and get the file from server as attachment. It will have headers including mime type. Generating an array of bytes at server and making a response is perfectly fine.